# AT commands for sim900 to find sim card number

Tags: at-command, sim900

Which AT commands is used to find the sim card number for SIM900 modem? I have a sim card which was bought long a ago and forget that number.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT+CNUM , but not all kind of sim cards support this function , 
for more check this http://www.electrodragon.com/w/SIM908_SIM900_Common_AT_Commands

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried that AT command too... but no solution. yes, i think all kind of sim card wont support this...

Answer (score 2):

AT+CNUM returns the mobile phone number stored on your SIM card. So if your mobile operator chose not to store your mobile phone number on the SIM card then you are out of luck. These days it is not very often that a mobile operator will do this.

The other answers here are a little misleading as it is not entirely a function as it is dependent on information being already stored on your SIM card.

Answer (score 1):

As @Belal mentioned, you can get this info from the `AT+CNUM` command. This is the only command .If your SIM card doesn't support it , I think there is no other way. Some time the network operator have assigned some special USSD code to get the SIM card number, but that is a feature that depends on the operator